# Random variable corresponding to product of density functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Suppose that $X_1, X_2$ are (probably independent) random variables and we have $X_1\sim f(x_1)$ and $X_2\sim g(x_2)$. Construct a new distribution for the new random variable $X$ as follows:
>   $$X\sim p(x)=\frac{1}{\kappa}f(x)g(x)$$
>   where $\kappa$ is a normalization factor such that the function is a density function. 
>   Is it possible to express $X$ as a function of $X_1$ and $X_2$ in a way that their PDF is $p(x)$?
>
> More formally, find a function $G$ such that 
>   $$X=G(X_1, X_2)\sim p(x)$$

Note: "$\sim$" denotes the probability density function of a random variable.

Note 2: If we had $p(x)=f(x)*g(x)$, where $*$ is the sign for convolution, then I think we may write $G(X_1, X_2) = X_1+X_2$.

Comment: A note. The formula for the sum expressed as a convolution of the pdfs requires independence.

Comment: Have you solved the problem for a single variable?

Comment: @leonbloy, No! Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question for single variable.

Comment: So you could regard this as the density of either $X_{1}$ or $X_{2}$ conditional on their being equal...

Comment: @Ali If $f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1)g(x_2)$, then $P(X_1=x, X_2=x) = f(x)g(x)$, but this is not a density function for a random variable.

Comment: Well no, because that doesn't include the normalisation.
It is right there in the definition of conditional probability
$p(A\mid B)=p(A\cap B)/p(B)$ where $A$ is the event that $X_{1}=x$ and $B$ is the event that
$X_{1}=X_{2}$ so that $p(B)=\kappa=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$.